# Need to execute all while controller under the test plan in jmeter

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

[view results tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqGzk.png)i'm using below schema in my test plan but only the first while controller with csv dataset gets executed.For the last 2 while controller there is no action

Test plan
        -------------->thread group

```
    ---------->while controller 1
             |___>csv data set 1

      ---------->while controller 2
             |___>csv data set 2

      ---------->while controller 3
             |___>csv data set 3
```

while controller is used in my test is to execute csv data set with one thread

i want jmeter to execute all while controller present in the test plan

Jmeter version 2.11

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

1. add a "debug sampler" and make its Name "Debug:
   ${your while condition} Then you can really see exactly what the
   value of your while condition is at the critical moment.
2. Give us a screen shot of your "view results tree" it is possible
   you are hitting an error and your thread is configured to stop on
   the first error

That should at least give some more info in the situation

Comment: Below the screenshot of view results tree here is what i see only only one while controller getting run

Comment: Added screenshot as link to the question - view results tree

Comment: looks like I have a typo in my orig comment that is in your debug samplers too (I mistakenly put [ instead of {", the var in the debug sampler should be exactly the same as what is in your while condition. please update that in your debug sampler to ${LocationA} rather then $[LocationA}